# PHP Going to the next element of the array every time you refresh

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am making a twitter bot and I have a long array in which from the bot has to tweet from, and I don't want it to tweet the same thing twice.

Therefore, I need a code which will go through the array in order, and without looping back to the start.
The array I have is called `$statusarray;` which contains the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
)
```

Therefore, I want a code which will start from `0 => a` and when I refresh goes to `1 => b`, then refresh again to go to `2 => c`, and so on without looping back.(Obviously don't want the numbers)

I was thinking of a for sentence like this:

```
    for($i=0;$i<infinite or very large number;$i++){
         echo $statusarray['$i'];
    }
```

But I know this will just echo all of the elements in the array in one long string, but I think I am on the right track(?).
What should I do?

Comment: You missed a change line , probably `<br />` after each `echo` in the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use session for example:

```
 <?php 
   session_start();
 ?> 

 <?php
   if(empty($_SESSION['counter']))
    $counter = $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
   else
    $counter = $_SESSION['counter']++;
   }



   for($i=$counter;$i<infinite or very large number;$i++){
    echo $statusarray['$i'];
   }
?>
```

Comment: @Masayuki Tonoki. If this solves your problem. Please accept my answer.

Comment: The problem is that the $_SESSION['counter'] is always empty when you refresh it. I think it is very close.

Comment: Add `session_start();` above your connection

Comment: It says Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by filename:9 which I think means line 9 of the same line which is where <?php starts from

Comment: Try to set it above the if statement

Comment: obvious syntax error. the PHP end tag close too soon, right?

Comment: I think it's the word empty try to change that in `if(!isset())`

Comment: No prob. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the previously tweeted keyin the session. On page reload, retrieve the key,increment by one and display the tweet.
Hope this help.